# What do I need to do to get the correct value o PI?

Tags: c

Greeting.
I am doing the following exercise: Run a program to determine an approximate value of π using the series shown below. The calculation is performed by generating a certain number of terms in the series. The number of terms to be considered is read from the standard input (keyboard) (greater than or equal to 30000).
Note: In the resolution of this issue, you cannot use functions from the math.h library of the C programming language.

[image]
example: input a value enter total terms >=30000: entering 30000 should give you the result o pi:3.141559
The prolem I'm having: Uppon entering the same value(30000)I am not getting the corret value o pi=3.14.... but instead it's something like:0.0067...

heres my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void){
    double numerator, denominator, pi=0.0;
    int k;
    printf("input a total number o terms >=30000:");
    for ( k=1;k<=30000;k++){
         scanf("%d",&k);

         if(k>=30000){
    
             if(k%2==0){
                 numerator=1;   
             }
             else {
                  numerator=-1;
             }
          }
          denominator=2.0*k+1.0;
          pi+=numerator/denominator;
          pi=4*pi;
          printf("value of PI is= %lf",pi);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong and how can I solve it pls?

Your time and attention are deeply appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: You do not explain what problem you are having.  First off, you need to properly indent your code so it is readable

Comment: Move the `scanf` *outside* of the loop.

Comment: You've not explained what problem you're having with the code you posted. It's hard to provide an answer to a problem you haven't yet provided.

Comment: Is the user supposed to input `n`, or `k`?

Comment: Since you are forbidden to use the math.h functions, what's your purpose for including the math.h header?

Comment: Why does the expression `denominator=2.0*k+1.0` not match the one in the problem statement?

Comment: `pi=4*pi;` at each iteration? That's not quite what the formula is asking for.

Comment: Never use scanf in (possibly malformed) user input without checking the return value.

Comment: The good news is that if you fix `n` for input, `k` for loop, remove `if (k>=30000)` (why is that even there?), fix the signs to match the formula, fix the denominator to match the formula, fix the 4* to match the formula... you will get the right result. So don't despair.

Comment: @SteveSummit It only asks me once and I did copy-paste it.

Comment: @cobaltbasalt Ah, right.  It only prints "input a total number o terms" once.  My mistake.  But it waits 30000 times for the user to type an answer...

Comment: `scanf` for `k` either in of out of the loop makes no sense, as it will get immediately overwritten by whatever comes 2nd.

Comment: what the ...? This question has been closed for (currently) 15 min, but an answer was just added 2 min ago ... how did that work? I don't have the ability to add an answer. Was it added before closure, deleted some time after, then undeleted after closure?

Comment: Restructure the program into 3 sections: a) input, b) computation loop, c) output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with what your implementation of the algorithm:

Try avoiding `scanf` ad `printf` inside the for loop.

Instead of getting the `k` variable from the user try and get the maximum value of `k`.

`denominator=2*k+1` is wrong if you follow the algorithm that you gave in your question and should be changed to `denominator=2*k-1`.

You repeat `pi*=4` every iteration.

I applied all those improvement and i get pi=3.141926 for just 3000 iterations.

Here a little help on how your `for` loop should look like:

```
for (int k=1;k<iterations;k++){
      numerator*=-1;
      denominator=2.0*k-1.0;
      pi+=numerator/denominator;
}
```